# How to reactivate a iPhone 5s which was originally activated from another account (Device already removed from previous iCloud)?

Tags: ios, icloud, apple-id, iphone

I bought my iPhone 5s about 3 days ago.Once i bought it i activated the phone from one of my friend's AppleID and password , because i needed to check if the phone functions well, before i leave the shop.but then after when i got back home i made a new apple account and used the phone with that account.

But since my phone is activated from my friend's iCloud i logged into account from his appleID and password. then i removed the device from his account. Then i erased the phone then rebooted it and setup a new i phone  with my AppleID and iCloud but still my phone is NOT Activated in my new account??

can someone please help me to activate my phone from my new account????

Comment: What does activating the phone on your new account mean? If you see the icons after sliding to unlock, your phone is activated. At that point, you would enter your account in iCloud and turn on Find my Phone to lock it to your account.

Comment: Yeah but when i go to itunes in my pc and login to my account i dont see my device registered to iCloud under my account information. :(

Comment: OK - now that makes some sense as I was misunderstanding what you wanted. I'll see if I can find the article and explain what to do there.

Comment: What does activating the phone on
your new account mean? If you see
the icons after sliding to unlock, your
phone is activated. At that point, you
would enter your account in iCloud
and turn on Find my Phone to lock it
to your account

Answer (score 3):

A full set of instructions are listed here: http://support.apple.com/kb/PH13695?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US

In short:

- you will need your friend to activate your phone at the Activation Screen during set up. The place you are stuck on.
- After that, reset the device by going to Settings > General > Reset.
- It will ask for your friends Apple ID details. Enter them.
- Once the phone has been reset, tell your friend to remove it from
  their Find my iPhone account.
- Restart the device and now finally register it under your own Apple
  ID.

Activation is a separate process. The device is still registered under your friend's Apple ID. And you are simply registered to use your Apple ID on the device. This is what you're getting hung up on. Resetting the device will allow you to activate it (register the device) under your own Apple ID. Signing out of your friends Apple ID in Settings does no affect device registration.

*And of note: If anyone may be attempting to bypass Activation Lock fraudulently or under false pretences, this cannot be done. Apple binds registration of the device to their servers. What that means is Apple will chase that device whenever it is connected to the Internet till the ends of time. Unless you can hack into Apple's servers, there is absolutely no way to bypass Activation Lock.*